# Cygwin git something wrong with https?

Tags: git, cygwin

**Edit:** It turns out that AVG put `git-remote-https.exe` in quarantine. Thanks @materzi.

I am trying to clone my repo with using Cygwin. However it fails and I get this message: `fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'.`  I havent used git in a while and this problem is new.

I have the two cygwin packages installed: curl  and libcurl-devel, which are both version 7.72.0-1.

I've tried to reinstall git 2.28.0-1 but I get an error that might be something to do with why I can't clone my repo.[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't replace a file that's in use on Windows, and something is using it.  If you have an editor open, that could be it.  Otherwise, try rebooting and see if you can reinstall then.

Comment: I have rebooted my pc multiples and go straight to the cygwin installer to reinstall git. I get the same problem though!

Comment: Then you'll want to hit “Continue” here and it should be installed when you restart the computer.  It's also possible that you have some sort of program on your system, such as a third-party antivirus or monitoring software, that's the cause of this.

Comment: Check your Antivirus log. It is strange that a git program is locked at boot

Comment: open a false positive issue with AVG. https://www.avg.com/en-us/false-positive-file-form